# How to split string with limit by the end in Python

Tags: python, string, split

I have the following string:

`"hello.world.foo.bar"`

and I want to split (with the `"."` as delimiter, and only want to get two elemets starting by the end) this in the following:

`["hello.world.foo", "bar"]`

How can I accomplish this? exist the limit by the end?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use [`str.rsplit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.rsplit) specifying maxsplit (the second argument) as `1`:

```
>>> "hello.world.foo.bar".rsplit('.', 1) # <-- 1: maxsplit
['hello.world.foo', 'bar']
```

Comment: So, split took from the left, and rsplit from the right side right ?   string.split('.', 1) and string.rsplit('.', 1) ?

Comment: @James, You're right. Without specifying the second argument, you get `['hello', 'world', 'foo', 'bar']` for both `string.split('.')` and `string.rsplit('.')`.